# outward traffic blocked

Tags: networking, firewall, sockets

So I have this web server which is accepting incoming traffic and is able to serve back replies.
However, if the server has to initiate any kind of traffic (icmp/tcp..) it fails:
Its been up for > 600 days, not sure how that would matter..

Symptoms:

```
root@server:~# ping -vv 10.0.10.80
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
ping: socket: Permission denied, attempting raw socket...
connect: Invalid argument
```

```
root@server:~# strace -e socket ping 8.8.8.8
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_ICMPV6) = 4
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
connect: Invalid argument
+++ exited with 2 +++
```

```
root@server:~# telnet 193.162.159.97 80
Trying 193.162.159.97...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Invalid argument
```

```
root@server:~# curl http://193.162.159.97
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

```
root@server:~# curl -vv http://193.162.159.97
* Rebuilt URL to: http://193.162.159.97/
*   Trying 193.162.159.97...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 193.162.159.97: Invalid argument
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

Environment:

```
root@server:~# ufw status
Status: inactive
```

```
root@server:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

```
root@server:~# iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 3265 packets, 274K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 2486 packets, 484K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

```
root@server:~# iptables -nvL -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
```

```
root@server:~# netstat -rn4
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens160
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens160
```

I also did a diff for 'net.ipv4' output from sysctl on this and a working server where I couldn't find any likely differences..

Whats going on here? How do I fix?

UPDATE!!!
I just tried this:

```
root@server:~# ping 10.8.1.235
connect: Invalid argument
root@server:~# route add -host 10.8.1.235 gw 192.168.11.1
root@server:~# ping 10.8.1.235
PING 10.8.1.235 (10.8.1.235) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.8.1.235: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=4.75 ms
64 bytes from 10.8.1.235: icmp_seq=2 ttl=61 time=4.78 ms
^C
--- 10.8.1.235 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.751/4.766/4.782/0.070 ms
```

My routing table:

```
root@server:~# route -vn  -4
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens160
10.8.1.235      192.168.11.1    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 ens160
192.168.11.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160
```

Comment: Maybe there's a Firewall on your GW 192.168.11.1 in this case? 
Please also show full output of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -nvL -t nat` for sake of completeness.

Comment: There is no firewall - but it seems that I cannot ping or connect to anything outside locally connected subnets (loopback + 192.168.11.0/24)..

Comment: Uhh, I just tried this.. see update with the new route..

Comment: what is your actual ip address on this machine? If its not in 192.168.11.0/24 range, then obviously the default route wouldn't work. As you mentioned in your own answer (don't do this ;-) ) this might have come from an old DHCP setup.

Comment: The output of _both_ `ip route` and `ip rule show` might help. Giving only the first tells only half the story. Is your gateway even a router? ... i.e. is it _routing_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion is that this VM originally was using dhcp, and the default route was installed by dhcp. Once I add a new (identical) default route:
route add -net 0.0.0.0/0 gw 192.168.11.1 then everything starts working again...

This is unfortunately not a server I am allowed to reboot at the moment, so we'll need to see if this permanently fixes this issue..

I would like to understand how I can see more details about the two default routes I have now, as the original one may not be working correctly..